# May I read deleted answers to my questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I've seen from my inbox a few lines of an answer to my question, but I didn't find it. I tried to see the edits of the previous answer but it does not look the same. I guess it was a new answer which has been deleted just before I could read it. Can I see deleted answers, in the same way I see previous edits? 
Of course, if the author decided to remove it, maybe it was not correct, but I am just curious to fully understand this site!

Comment: If you post a link to the question, we can copy the content of the deleted question.

Comment: Thank you, anyway it's not a great issue this time, I already got an answer which solves my question... maybe the author is just shy! :D

Comment: Or, as happened to me today, the author misread the question, posted an answer, then realized the mistake and corrected for that by deleting the answer..

Comment: If you are really curious you can always join chat and hope for a 10k user to copy you the contents of the deleted answer.

Comment: Upvote this [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) that asks for this ability.

Comment: @LanceRoberts - Isn't that feature request for own questions/answers? While here OP is asking for answers ***on*** his question. :-) (By the way I am already in favour of that request.)

Comment: @hims056, good point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't see deleted answer (or post) if you do not have 10K+ reputation on the particular site. To see the deleted answers you need to gain 10000 reputation.

Comment: Why such a high requirement? I only want to see the deleted answer to *[my own question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1073770/191910)* because it seemed very useful. It didn't actually answer the question but showed what looked like a good way to tackle it. I was going to do it then, but was busy, then forgot about it, but now I would like to tackle it using the idea from that answer. Will I have to wait for ages until my reputation grows high enough before I can have a go?